# Issue with obtaining input form for chat system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Currently having issues making a chat system. It's been a long day, so my brain has been half off when trying to code this.
In short, I'm trying to make a chat system by using PHP and the jQuery framework for JavaScript. After discovering that solely using PHP wouldn't work, I read that I could use Ajax to prevent reloading the page when trying to send a message (reloading the page results in the chat username being reset). I've written the code, and I've tried obtaining the value from an input form in my main code, which I personally believe is the issue here.
The portion of the code which I'm certain is affecting this is as follows:

```
<!-- CHAT BOX -->
    <div class="content" style="width:700px;">
        <div class="container" style="height:500px;border-top-right-radius:3px;border-top-left-radius:3px;border-bottom:0px solid black;overflow-y:scroll;">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var msgdisp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            msgdisp.open("GET","chatlog/log.txt");
            var lines = msgdisp.result.split('\n');
            for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
                document.write(line);
            }

        </script>
      </div>
        <form>
            <input name="chateroo" placeholder="Chat" style="width:678px;height:8px;text-align:left;padding:10px;border-radius:0px;border-bottom-right-radius:3px;border-bottom-left-radius:3px;border:1px solid grey;"/>           </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var message = (username + ": "+document.getElementByName("chateroo").value());
        $.ajax({
            url: "include/chatsvs.php",
            data: {chat: message},
            type: 'post',
            success: alert('Successfully sent message');
        });
    </script>
    </div>
```

the variable 'username' is created earlier on in the code by creating the username with PHP and then echoing that value to a JavaScript variable to be used later on. In case it's important, this is the section where I set the username.

```
<?php
    //Setting the username
    echo("<div id=\"inputmessage\" style=\"padding:10px;width:500px;background-color:white;position:relative;display:inline-block;margin-top:20px;\">");
    if(isset($_POST['name_input'])) {

        $chatname = $_POST['name_input'];
        echo("<h2>Chatting as $chatname</h2>");
    }
    else {
        echo("<h2>Set your username:</h2>");

    }
    echo("<form method=\"POST\">");
    if(isset($chatname)) {

        echo("<input name=\"name_input\" id=\"nameipt\" type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Change username\" style=\"text-align:left;background-color:#E3E3E3;color:black;border-radius:1px;\">");
    }
    else {
        echo("<input name=\"name_input\" type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Set username\" style=\"text-align:left;background-color:#E3E3E3;color:black;border-radius:1px;\">");
    }

    echo("</form></div>");

    if(isset($chatname)) {

        echo("<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        var nameset = true;
        var username = $chatname;
        </script>");
    }
    ?>
```

I have an external PHP file which logs the message into a text file to then be read into the container, which is something else which I should probably fix.

If anyone can help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it. Keep in mind I'm only a computer science student. A lot of technical vocabulary might go over my head, as well as extremely advanced code. I'm not too bad, but definitely not an expert.

I've learnt HTML, CSS, PHP, and understand the FUNDAMENTAL basics of jQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont include jquery code in the middle of HTML not good coding practice.

```
        <!-- CHAT BOX -->
            <div class="content" style="width:700px;">
                <div class="container" style="height:500px;border-top-right-radius:3px;border-top-left-radius:3px;border-bottom:0px solid black;overflow-y:scroll;">
              </div>
                <form>
                    <input name="chateroo" id="chateroo" placeholder="Chat" style="width:678px;height:8px;text-align:left;padding:10px;border-radius:0px;border-bottom-right-radius:3px;border-bottom-left-radius:3px;border:1px solid grey;"/>           </form>
            </div>
<!-- Juery Code-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var msgdisp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    msgdisp.open("GET","chatlog/log.txt");
                    var lines = msgdisp.result.split('\n');
                    for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
                        document.write(line);
                    }

    var chatMsg=$("#chateroo").val();   
    var message = ("username" + ":"+ chatMsg);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "include/chatsvs.php",
                    data: {chat: message},
                    type: 'post',
                    success: alert('Successfully sent message');
                });
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ddtxra/60wme3pf/

Comment: Thanks for the response.
However, it still seems to completely refresh the page upon chatting.
Cheers for the help with the ajax and jQuery code, I'm really new to this (as in I discovered jQuery and DOM yesterday)

Comment: @RNash on button click disable form submit and return false. If you like previous ans please vote up

Comment: Could you put that into code? I don't know exactly where to put that. Again, I'm extremely new to this. By the way, I just upvoted your comment, but it's not publicly registering. :)